# Windows Form アプリケーションでSQLServerへ接続できない

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, sql-server

環境
Visual Studio Express for Desktop
SQL Server Express 2014
C# Windows Form アプリケーション

にて開発を行っております。

VisualStudioでアプリケーションを実行した際は問題無くSQLServerに接続されるのですが
ビルドしたexeを直接実行すると

```
「このログインで要求されたデータベース "dbo" を開けません。ログインに失敗しました。
ユーザー 'sa' はログインできませんでした。」
```

という例外が発生するようになりました。
このような場合、まず何を疑えばよいのでしょうか。

接続文字列は以下になります。

```
@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;"
                       + @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;"
                       + "Database=dbo;"
                       + "integrated security=false;"
                       + "User ID=sa;"
                       + "Password=xxxx;";
```

Comment: `Integrated Security`を有効にしているのであれば`User ID`と`Password`を指定する必要はないのでは

Comment: @pgrho さま
失礼しました。 
Integrated Securityはfalseでした。本文を修正しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Server Express ユーザーインスタンス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms254504(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)に

> `Integrated Security`が`true`に設定されます。ユーザーインスタンスに接続するにはWindows認証が必要です。SQL Serverログインはサポートされません。

とあるように`sa`でのログインは制限されているようです。

---

[管理者以外のユーザーのためのユーザーインスタンス](https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms143684(v=sql.90).aspx)で説明されていますが

> ユーザーインスタンスは、管理者以外のユーザーが各自のアカウントでSQL Serverのローカルバージョンを実行できるようにする機能です。

とあるように実行したユーザー権限で動作させる機能ですのでそもそもWindows認証が必須です。これはユーザーインスタンス登場当時からの制限であり途中から変更されたものではありません。

Comment: @sayuriさま
ご回答ありがとうございます。
SQL Serverログインはサポート外だったのですね。

以前はWindows認証で接続出来ていたのですが、ある時から接続出来なくなってしまい
「このログインで要求されたデータベース "dbo" を開けません。ログインに失敗しました。
ユーザー 'xxx’ はログインできませんでした。」

という結果が返ってくるようになってしまいました。
原因がわからず、SQL Serverログインに切り替えようとしていたのですがサポート外となるとWindows認証の失敗を解決するしかなさそうですね。

もう少し調べてみようと思います。

Comment: @eos さん、誤解されているようなので加筆しました。SQL Serverログインとユーザーインスタンス（`AttachDbFilename`）が組み合わせられない、という制限なだけです。

Comment: @sayuriさま
失礼致しました。丁寧に説明いただきありがとうございます。
リンク先の解説についても読ませていただきます。

Comment: Windows認証に変更し、接続できましたので解決とさせて頂きます。